# Copy column with VBA if date equals month

Tags: excel, date, copy, vba

I would like to have a macro to copy column of data if the data matches.  Each month the report spits out the current month of data, and i have to copy and paste the column B data into the the column that is the same date of the month.

[image: Sample Spreedsheet]

1. In cell A2 I enter the date.  It is always the first day of the month to represent the month something simple. Example: `7/1/17`
2. Column B has all the date that need to be copied. B4:B660
3. In columns H3 thru S3 are the months of the year. 
   (H3) `7/1/2017` (I3) `8/1/2017` (J3) `9/1/2017` (K3) `10/1/2017` ... (S3) `6/1/2018`

So if I type a date in A2, if that equals the same date in one of the cells in H3 thru S3, copy column B below that date in H4 thru S4.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You will need to show us the code you already have, because StackOverflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: I suggest you to better explain your issue (take a picture of your screen) and your target (what do you expect to obtain with the macro and where the results are gonna be).